# A differen "Drag and Drop" images in Tkinter (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, events, binding, tkinter, python-3.3

I'm trying to make it possible for my program's user to drag an image from a widget and drop it in another without removing the image from its first position.

I thought on using a `TopLevel` for this. Upon a click+drag event, a `TopLevel`, containing the same image, would pop up right above the clicked image on the `event.x` and `event.y` position. Then it would change its position along with the mouse and only upon `ButtonRelease-1` the `TopLevel` would be destroyed.

If the Button Release event was triggered on the master x and y coordinates corresponding to where is my other widget (in the case, a canvas), then it would trigger a `canvas.create_image()` using the `event.x` and `event.y`.

The problems I'm facing are:

1. Only 1 `TopLevel` should appear at once, but I had no success limiting it. Several windows overlap as I click and drag the mouse.
2. I can't make `Toplevel.geometry` use the bound event's x and y positions.
3. How to make the `Toplevel` display the same image as the user clicked, without magic numbers and variables?

Here's my code so far:

```
class animalImgList():

    def __init__(self, a):
        #Constructor
        initX = 75
        initY =  40

        animalList = ['pig2.jpg', 'pig3.jpg', 'pig4.jpg']

        for a in animalList:
            vars(self)[a+'img'] = PIL.Image.open(a)

            vars(self)[a+'tkimg'] = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(vars(self)[a+'img'])

            vars(self)[a+'labelName'] = Label(anmlCanvas, image=vars(self)[a+'tkimg'])
            vars(self)[a+'canvasImg'] = anmlCanvas.create_image(initX, initY,image=(vars(self)[a+'tkimg']))
            initY = initY + 70

            anmlImgList = []
            anmlImgList.append(vars(self)[a+'canvasImg'])

            imgTags = anmlCanvas.addtag_all("img")
            anmlCanvas.tag_bind("img", "<Button-1>", self.createImg)

    def createImg(self, event):

        newImg = Toplevel(root)
        newImg.geometry("50x40"+"+"+ x+"+"+y)

        newImgMsg = Message(newImg, text="This is supposed to be an image")
        newImgMsg.pack()

        newImg.update_idletasks()
        newImg.overrideredirect(True)

        createImgOpen = True

        if createImgOpen == True:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To drag an image between two canvases without removing the image from the first canvas.

The idea is the following:

- When the user clicks on the canvas `can1` (`click1` function):

  - get the item the user clicked on with `can1.find_closest`
  - get its image with `can1.itemcget`
  - create a toplevel containing the image
  - bind mouse motion to drag along the toplevel: for that you need to use the `event.x_root` and `event.y_root` to change the toplevel's geometry.
- When the user releases the left mouse button (`release` function):

  - unbind mouse motion
  - if the toplevel is inside the canvas `can2`, create the image in `can2` at the mouse position
  - destroy the toplevel

This way, there can be only one toplevel because each time the button is released, the toplevel is destroyed.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class DragToplevel(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, image, x, y):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.geometry('+%i+%i' % (x, y))

        self.image = image

        self.label = tk.Label(self, image=image, bg='red')
        self.label.pack()

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.geometry('+%i+%i' % (x, y))


root = tk.Tk()

can1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='white')
can2 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='white')

can1.pack(side='left')
can2.pack(side='right')
root.geometry('800x800')

im = tk.PhotoImage('tux', master=root, file='/home/juliette/Images/tux_mini.png')
drag_id = ''
dragged = None
can1.create_image(100, 200, image=im)

def click1(event):
    global drag_id, dragged
    items = can1.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    if items:
        image = can1.itemcget(items[0], 'image')
        dragged = DragToplevel(root, image, event.x_root, event.y_root)
        drag_id = root.bind('<Motion>', lambda e: dragged.move(e.x_root, e.y_root))


def release(event):
    global drag_id, dragged
    root.unbind('<Motion>',  drag_id)
    drag_id = ""
    xr, yr = event.x_root, event.y_root
    x2, y2 = can2.winfo_rootx(), can2.winfo_rooty()
    w2, h2 = can2.winfo_width(), can2.winfo_height()
    if dragged and xr >= x2 and xr < x2 + w2 and yr >= y2 and yr < y2 + h2:
        can2.create_image(xr - x2, yr - y2, image=dragged.image, anchor='nw')
    if dragged:
        dragged.destroy()
        dragged = None


can1.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', click1)
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)

root.mainloop()
```